# Unfortunately, app has stopped working?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

I'm getting an error when I try to run my application. This is what I get in my logcat

```
`02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857): Process: com.colourity.snatsh, PID: 5857
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.colourity.snatsh/com.colourity.snatsh.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at com.colourity.snatsh.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-21 20:31:41.551: E/AndroidRuntime(5857):     ... 9 more
`
```

My code for the corresponding issue.

```
    package com.colourity.snatsh;


import com.colourity.snatsh.R;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.colourity.snatsh.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.colourity.snatsh.model.NavDrawerItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

I also get the pop up that say's `Unfortunately, app has stopped.` I'm not sure where to go from here, since I'm fairly new. Let me know if I need to post any code.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5 , can you post your code?

Comment: Hmmm, access to the code is always a helpful tool when debugging, I find. Call me pampered.

Comment: In particular, near line 76 of MainActivity.java.

Comment: Done. Code is above @saiarcot895

Comment: Added my code. @ABoschman

Comment: You only needed to post the code around line 76 (or the code in onCreate). In this case, I'm assuming line 76 is `navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));`. If so, then `navMenuTitles` has a size of 5 and doesn't have anything at index 5.

Comment: Can you show an example of what it would look like when I have something at index 5? @saiarcot895

Comment: navMenuTitles[5] non-existent , this is why ther is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException , so verifiy R.array.nav_drawer_items if it contains 5 or 6 elements (i think 5 so that there is an error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5
```

Your array does not have 6 elements

```
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));
```

Array indexes start with 0 in pretty much every programming language case you where unaware.